Relation between 16 $\mathbf{CP}^2$ and $\overline{K3}$
In bordism theory and algebraic topology, 4d spin bordism group is generated by $K3$ surface, while 4d $SO$ bordism group  generated by $\mathbf{CP}^2$.
$K3$'s 4-manifold signature is $- 16$
and $\mathbf{CP}^2$'s 4-manifold signature is $+1$.

Are there ways that showing the 16 copies of $\mathbf{CP}^2$ is cobordant to the orientation reversing of $K3$? Namely, are there 5-manifold making these 17 disjoint pieces of manifolds (16 copies of $\mathbf{CP}^2$ and $\overline{K3}$) null bordant?

Relatedly $\mathbf{CP}^2$ is a non-spin manifold. The $K3$ is a spin manifold.
Can 16 copies of $\mathbf{CP}^2$ be a spin manifold in some modified way? So that the spin version of the 16 copies of $\mathbf{CP}^2$ becomes cobordant to $\overline{K3}$?



[Note: This answer was updated according to @MarcoGolla's comment to avoid a potential circularity.]

(1) The existence of such a bordism is already answered by your question: "$\mathbb{CP}^2$ generates $\Omega^{SO}_4$" literally means any closed oriented smooth 4-manifold is oriented cobordant to some copies of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ or $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$.
So I suppose that you are asking for an explicit bordism.
As @MarcoGolla pointed out, there is a diffeomorphism
$$K3\mathbin\#\mathbb{CP}^2\ \simeq\ 4\mathbb{CP}^2\mathbin\#19\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}\,,$$
by Exercise 8.3.4(d) in Gompf and Stipsicz's book 4-manifolds and Kirby Calculus.
Tracing the connected sums on both sides, we obtain a compact oriented smooth 5-manifold $W_1$ with boundary
$$\partial W_1\ \simeq\ K3\amalg 20\mathbb{CP}^2\amalg 4\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}\,.$$
Gluing $W_1$ with 4 copies of $\mathbb{CP}^2\times I$ along the boundary, we obtain a compact oriented smooth 5-manifold $W_2$ with boundary
$$\partial W_2\ \simeq\ K3\amalg 16\mathbb{CP}^2\,.$$
Hence $W_2$ is what you want.
In addition to 4-manifolds and Kirby Calculus mentioned above, Scorpan's book The Wild World of 4-manifolds is also a good place to learn about 4-manifolds.

(2) I don't quite understand the question.
If you have a connected spin manifold, it induces a spin structure on each connected component of its boundary.

$K3#\mathbb{CP}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $4\mathbb{CP}^2#19\overline{\mathbb{CP}}\vphantom{\mathbb{P}}^2$, by Exercise 8.3.4(d) in Gompf and Stipsicz's book 4-manifolds and Kirby calculus.

By the way, as far as I recall Wall's proof uses the existence of the cobordism, so the argument you're presenting might be a bit circular. (If you use the explicit diffeomorphism I suggested, then it isn't circular, though. Also, there might be other proofs of Wall's theorem that do not rely on the existence of the cobordism.)

TeX note: To get \# to space as a binary operator, you can use \mathbin\# rather than \ \#\  (or use something like \newcommand\csum{\mathbin\#} to avoid re-typing that repeatedly).  The binary version of the sum-like operator \coprod is \amalg; compare, for example, $K3 \amalg 2\mathbb CP^2$ to $K3 \coprod 2\mathbb CP^2$.

@MarcoGolla Indeed, the construction you suggested is far better. I'm not aware of an alternative proof of Wall's theorem that does not rely on h-cobordism, so I admit my argument is a bit circular... Would you like to write an answer? Or would you mind if I modify my answer using the diffeomorphism you suggested?

The main idea is yours---go ahead and modify your answer.
